# Display selected value in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list like this:

```
<select id="ddlLanguage" name="culture">
    <option value="null" >Language:</option>
    <option value="ar-jo">Arabic</option>
    <option value="en-us">English</option>
    <option value="fr-FR">French</option>
    <option value="es-cl">Spanish</option>
</select>
```

If I select "Arabic",the drop down list should display "Arabic". But am always getting "Language".

**EDIT**

I got the answer by using Viewbag

Script:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#ddlLanguage').val("@ViewBag.Msg");
            $('#ddlLanguage').change(function () {
                $('#currentCulture').val($(this).val());
                $(this).parents("form").submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

In the controller i have set value of ViewBag.Msg.

```
ViewBag.Msg = ddlLanguage
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'if I select Arabic'? programmatically? You should select 'ar-jo' in that case

Comment: I want to display arabic in dropdown .But i should get ar-jo as value.it is used to change culture

Comment: @Mizbella can u create link

Answer (score 0):

Update your dropdown with code given below:

```
<select id="ddlLanguage" name="culture">
    <option value="null" >Language:</option>
    <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I cant change value like that

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
$('#ddlLanguage').change(function(){    
   alert( $(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the selected attribute to selected on the given option.
$("your option").attr("selected", "selected");